# Error:(34, 12) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

ı have trouble with this error, and i can not see any sensible mistake from code

```
package driver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class DriverFactory {

    // Get a new WebDriver Instance.
    // There are various implementations for this depending on browser. The required browser can be set as an environment variable.
    // Refer http://getgauge.io/documentation/user/current/managing_environments/README.html
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {

        String browser = System.getenv("BROWSER");
        if (browser == null) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }
        switch (browser)
        {
            case "IE":
                WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
                return new InternetExplorerDriver();
            case "FIREFOX":
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                return new FirefoxDriver();
            default:
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                return new ChromeDriver();

        }
    }
}
```

Error:(34, 12) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Comment: which is line 34?

Comment: ıt refer to line after "return new ChromeDriver();" statement

Comment: Sure it's the correct file? Did you save it and compile it after your last changes?

Comment: try to save you files, clean and re-compile

Answer (score 0):

It solved with review pom.xml dependencies 
It should be just like this,

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.thoughtworks.gauge.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>gauge-archetype-java</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.gauge</groupId>
        <artifactId>gauge-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.gauge.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gauge-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <specsDir>specs</specsDir>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```